# Adding a $_GET variable to the URL for each checked checkbox

Tags: php, function, variables, filter, get

I have a HTML form that has 20 checkboxes in it and I'm using the isset() function from PHP to check whether or not each box was checked upon submission.

I would like the PHP script to add a $_GET variable to the URL for each checkbox that is checked.

For example, if checkbox #1 and #3 were checked, I want a header() function to redirect the user to http://domain.com/form.php?one=checked&three=checked but if #4, #7, and #19 were checked, I'd like the redirected URL to be http://domain.com/form.php?four=checked&seven=checked&nineteen=checked

Is this possible or is there a better way to do this?

P.S. This is for an advanced search feature to filter out results based on what boxes are checked

Comment: If you use a regular web `form` element with `GET`, when they submit the form, they will be redirected in the way you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array that maps checkbox numbers to parameter names, then iterate over the checked boxes and [build a query string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this should be done in client-side using javascript before the form is submitted.

For example use javascript to alter the action attribute of the form when a checkbox is (de)selected. Of listen and wait till the onsubmit event is fired on that form and then add the slelected checkboxes to the action attribute of the form